# Is there an r function that will repeat a number, limited by ";" for x number of times

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column of data, and I would like to create a new column with the value in column$input copied 'x' times and limited by ";"

```
x = 3

input = structure(list(input = c(67L, 24L, 72L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

output = structure(list(input = c(67L, 24L, 72L, 3L), output = c("67;67;67", 
"24;24;24", "72;72;72", "3;3;3")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I cannot for the life of me think of a simple way of doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, actually.

```
library(tidyverse)
input$output = map_chr(input$input, ~ paste(rep(.x, x), collapse=";"))
```

or, if you really, really prefer to do it with dplyr

```
input <- input %>% rowwise() %>% 
           mutate(output = paste(rep(input, 3), collapse=";"))
```

Aaaand with base R:

```
output$input <- sapply(input$input, \(x) paste(rep(x, 3), collapse=";"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using the tidyverse...

```
output <- input %>% 
  mutate(output = map_chr(input, ~paste(rep(., x), collapse = ";")))
```

Comment: map_chr is part of purrr which is part of tidyverse, so I think you meant "dplyr" or "dplyr/pipes". But if I were to use pipes I would use rowwise (as shown in my reply) to avoid the map_chr and too much nesting.